# How should i remove warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency"?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a function that use in `useEffect` and click event, then throw warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency", how should i remove the warning?

```
// location is react router location
const Component = ({ location }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const { id } = parseLocation(location);
    fetchDataFromServer(id).then(data => setData(data));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <button onClick={fetchData)}>reload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

then i try this, but the warning still exist

```
// location is react router location
const Component = ({ location }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = (l) => {
    // l is location
    const { id } = parseLocation(l);
    fetchDataFromServer(id).then(data => setData(data));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(location);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <button onClick={() => fetchData(location)}>reload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can put `// eslint-disable-next-line` above `}, [location]);`

Comment: Seems like you could add fetchData to the dependency array also

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas When someone has a linter error, I wouldn't suggest disabling the linter error unless you explain *why* it's safe to ignore the issue.  In this case, I don't think that's the best choice.

Comment: @SeanMC That's going to cause the `useEffect` to run every render - I think it'll actually cause an infinite loop, as each render will trigger `fetchData`, which triggers `setState` which causes a new render.

Comment: I highly recommend reading Dan Abramov's [Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/); I tried to give the abridged version in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the `exhaustive-deps` rule is to prevent hooks from reading stale props or state.  The issue is that since `fetchData` is defined within the component, as far as the linter is concerned, it could be accessing stale `props` or state (via closure).

One solution is to pull `fetchData` out of the component and pass it everything it needs: (it's already being passed the location):

```js
const fetchData = (l, setData) => {
  // l is location
  const { id } = parseLocation(l);
  fetchDataFromServer(id).then(data => setData(data));
}

const Component = ({ location }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(location, setData);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <button onClick={() => fetchData(location, setData)}>reload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since `fetchData` isn't defined outside the component, the linter knows that it won't access state or props, so it isn't an issue for stale data.

---

To be clear, though, your original solution is *correct*, from a runtime perspective, since `fetchData` doesn't read state or props - but the linter doesn't know that.

You could simply disable the linter, but it'd be easy to accidentally introduce bugs later on (if `fetchData` is ever modified) that way.  It's better to have the linter rule verifying correctness, even if it means some slight restructuring of code.

---

#### Alternative solution

An alternative solution which leverages closure instead of passing the location into `fetchData`:

```
const Component = ({ location }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    // Uses location from closure
    const { id } = parseLocation(location);
    fetchDataFromServer(id).then(data => setData(data));

  // Ensure that location isn't stale
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();

  // Ensure that fetchData isn't stale
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <button onClick={fetchData}>reload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This approach lets you avoid passing `location` into `fetchData` every time you call it.  However, with this approach it's important to make sure to avoid stale state and props.

If you omitted the `[fetchData]` dep to `useEffect`, the effect would only run once, and new data wouldn't be fetched when `location` changed.

But if you have `fetchData` in the deps for `useEffect` but don't wrap `fetchData` in `useCallback`, the `fetchData` function is a new function every render, which would cause the `useEffect` to run every render (which would be bad).

By wrapping in `useCallback`, the `fetchData` function is only a new function whenever the `location` changes, which causes the `useEffect` to run at the appropriate point.

Comment: It works, but need to pass `setData` to `fetchData`. `const fetchData = ({ location, setData }) => { //... }`

Comment: Ah, good catch.  Fixed.  Personally, I'd probably use the `useCallback` form, myself, in that case.